# Getting the status from git diff

Tags: bash, git, shell

I'm running the following command from within a checked out branch

```
git diff main --name-status
```

This will list all the files in branch and the status

```
A    path/to/some/file.py
D    path/to/another/file.py
```

I want to work with the file path but base the logic on that first character (status). Where `A` is the file is being added, and `D` is the file is being removed.

This is my pseudo code

```
files = git diff main --name-status

for file in files
    if file.status = 'A'
     # handle add logic
    else if file.status = 'D'
      # handle delete logic
```

How can I do something like this? I've also found this flag I could use

```
--diff-filter=A
```

This will only return files that have been added. Can someone give me an example of how best to store the results and loop over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the provided solution with a single `git diff` command

```
while read -r status file; do
   case $status in
    A)
        echo "status A: $file"
        ;;
    D)
        echo "status D: $file"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown status: $file" >&2
        ;;
    esac


done < <(git --no-pager diff main --name-status --diff-filter=D --diff-filter=A | sort -k 1,1)
```

Output:

```
status A: file1
status A: file2
status A: file3
status D: CONTRIBUTING.adoc
status D: images/login.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the filter flag was the way to go

```sh
for f in $(git diff main --name-only --diff-filter=A); do
    # Handle Added Files
done

for f in $(git diff main --name-only --diff-filter=D); do
    # Handle Deleted Files
done
```

Comment: Be aware that there are a lot of other letters. When I scripted something related to this, my strategy was: only grab the list of names, and skip files that didn't exist (in my context, I could guarantee that the index never differed from HEAD).

Comment: Also, besides what @o11c noted, remember that `git diff` is a *porcelain* command that obeys your (per-user) configuration. This means that depending on how you set `diff.renames` you might or might not get `R` status codes. To avoid depending on your personal configuration, consider using Git's *plumbing* commands. Of course if you're writing personal scripts, it's OK to depend on personal configurations. :-)